"Could not activate Python COM server" with xlwings
I'm writing code using Python and I have encountered an unresolved issue.
I'm trying to create an Excel formula using the Python module xlwings to summarize sentences based on keywords. I plan to utilize the API of ollama LLM in the local environment for keyword summarization. (This task is being conducted within the company, and due to security concerns, using online LLM is not feasible.)
Below is the code I have attempted to write.
import xlwings as xw
import requests

@xw.func
def ollama_keyword(ref_cell):
    # ref_cell
    sentence = xw.Range(ref_cell).value
    
    #  prompt
    keywords = input("Please summarize the sentence using a minimum of two and a maximum of five keywords.: ")
    
    # ollama API response
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:11434", json={"sentence": sentence, "keywords": keywords})
    
    # summary
    summary = response.json()["summary"]
    
    return summary

After saving the above code and executing formulas in Excel, an error message such as
 "Could not activate Python COM server, hr = -2147221164" 

is encountered in Excel. I'm not sure what the problem might be, so I'm asking if anyone knows a solution.
I thought it was a problem with the COM server for communication between Python and Ollama, and I tried to find a way to activate the server. However, I concluded that xlwings and COM server activation are not related to each other.

Have a look at https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1502 and also https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1584

Thank you for your help. I found the cause of the issue. It was not a problem with the Python code, but with the format of the ollama API call.
r = requests.post(
"http://localhost:11434/api/chat",
json={"model": "mistral:latest", "messages": messages, "stream": True},
)
I have fixed the issue by modifying the code. Have a great day!
